# dc.js external control to apply crossfilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js

I have a time bar chart that allows crossfiltering when selecting a particular date range. It is difficult to see the exact date range one has selected in the chart itself, so I would like to add an external date range selector for a user to enter a `From` and `To` date range via input controls, either a double slider or simple date inputs. Looking at the dc.js api, it seems that using the `.filter()` function would be enough to apply the selection. I am testing in the javascript console and encounter the following behavior.

```
var dtgFormat = d3.time.format("%m-%Y");
moveChart.filter([dtgFormat.parse("06-2010"),dtgFormat.parse("06-2011")])
dc.redrawAll()
```

expanded code from actual dc chart generating javascript:

```
//crossfilter.version = "1.3.12";
var moveChart = dc.barChart('#monthly-move-chart');

d3.csv("/data/acuityData.csv", function (data) {

// format our data
var dtgFormat = d3.time.format("%m-%Y");
var dtgFormat2 = d3.time.format("%a %e %b %H");

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.dtg1=d.dayOfWeek;
d.dtg= dtgFormat.parse(d.month+"-"+d.year)  ;
d.dtg2=d.year;
d.mag= d.acuityInitial;
d.depth= d.waitTime;
d.dispositions= d.disposition;

});
// Dimension by month
  var moveMonths = facts.dimension(function (d) {
return d.dtg;
});
 // Group by total movement within month
  var monthlyMoveGroup = moveMonths.group().reduceCount(function (d)    {
return (d.dtg);
});

 moveChart
  .width(900)
  .height(40)
  .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40})
  .dimension(moveMonths)
  .group(monthlyMoveGroup)
  .centerBar(true)
  .gap(1)
  .mouseZoomable(true)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dtg; })))
  .xUnits(d3.time.months)
  .elasticX(true);
```

moveChart.yAxis().ticks(0);
After applying this function I can see the selection being applied to the particular graph but the crossfiltering does not happen until I actually interact with the rendered selection, via clicking or dragging, etc. Her e is a screenshot before clicking:
[image]

And here is an image after clicking:[image]

I'm wondering if there is a different way to force the click, i've tried adding a jQuery function that `.click()` the `rect` that d3 applies to show the filtered area but I am thinking there must be a better way to apply the external filter than this seemingly hack-y approach.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Are you using some sort of async version of Crossfilter? Otherwise I think you may need to put together a working example of this.

Comment: The 3 commands i've typed I enter in chrome's javascript console. i hit enter after each command.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about what version of Crossfilter you are using. My suspicion is that you have asynchronous application of the filter at some point. Please either provide all your code or (better) a working example of the problem that those trying to answer the question can easily run.

Comment: ok i have made some edits to include more source code that of which actual generates the monthly move chart, and crossfilter.version = "1.3.12"; as shown there as well. afaik im not using any different type of crossfilter, just whatever was downloaded directly from their page.

Comment: I think if you don't use the filter objects, it displays correctly but does not filter correctly, as described here.